# "Schedule" my program with asynctask?

Tags: android

I am trying to display images in a gridView. The images come from an research on an ElasticSearch server. The user give a keyword in a textfield, the result of the query on ElasticSearch is  list of string (urls of images) and the images are displayed in the gridView.

The action when I press a button in order to make the research :

```
public void sendMessage(View view){

    imgAdapter.clearmThumbIds();  //mThumbs is a list of string (urls image)

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();          
    try {
        eSearchElastic.ESE(imgAdapter,message);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Etape 2");
    gridView.setAdapter(imgAdapter);


}
```

eSearchElastic.java

```
public static void ESE (final ImageAdapter imgAdapter,final String keyword)throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //Build the query, connect to ElasticServer and receive a list or urls of image as answer
         System.out.println("Etape 1");
        return null;
    }

};
task.execute();}
```

And the result of this print Etape2 before Etape1 and I would like this line "gridView.setAdapter(imgAdapter)" is executed only after the background process/thread of eSearchElastic is finished.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `gridView.setAdapter(imgAdapter);` in the [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method inside your `AsyncTask` instead of calling it from `sendMessage()`. That is guaranteed to be called only after the `doInBackground()` method finishes, and will be called on the main thread, so it's safe to touch the UI.

eg:

```
public static void ESE (final GridView gridView, final ImageAdapter imgAdapter, final String keyword) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Build the query, connect to ElasticServer and receive a list or urls of image as answer
            System.out.println("Etape 1");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            gridView.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: When I add the method onPostExecute(), I have a warning :"The method onPostExecute() from AsyncTask<void,void,void> is never used locally" ?

Comment: Make sure you have a Void parameter: onPostExecute(Void result) { }

Comment: Thx now it works, but I am not sure to understand why I need a void parameter and this line :  super.onPostExecute(result);

Comment: If you look at the AsyncTask docs, you'll see that it takes three generic types: Params, Progress, and Result. Each of these must inherit from java.lang.Object. void (lowercase) is a built-in type and not an Object, but Void *does* inherit from java.lang.Object and is basically just a wrapper for a void, so it's allowed as a generic type.

I am not sure if it's strictly necessary to call super.onPostExecute(result) in an AsyncTask, but generally speaking, when you override a non-abstract class method you should usually call the base class's method via super.<methodName>().